# What can cause a mistaken UI control hierarchy in Coded UI Test?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm creating automatic tests with VS 2012 and Coded UI Test. When I record a test with our WPF application and make a MouseClick on a ListBoxItem (we use ListBoxes as menus) I got at the end a mistaken UI control hierarchy in the UI Control Map.

I would expect the following tree:

```
WPF-Window/TabControl/TabPage/RadExpander/MainMenuListBox/SelectedMenuListItem
```

But I get the following - as I said - mistaken tree:

```
WPF-Window/RadExpander/MainMenuListBox/SelectedMenuListItem
```

When I play back the recording, the controls under the `WPF-Window` cannot be found, because the tree is not complete.

When I record a DoubleClick on the ListBox control I get the right tree.

All controls have AutomationIds.

What can be the cause for that mistake in the UI control tree?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:
I have made now a smaller version of the WPF.
When i make a single MouseClick on one of the ListBoxItems, the tree is okay.
But when i make a DoubleClick on one of the items, the tree is wrong.

Comment: I believe Coded UI deliberately excludes some items from the tree, but I cannot find the Microsoft page to describe how that is done. Hence I think that you problem is not related to missing items in the tree. The Coded UI content index has several items on handling WPF, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

Comment: When i replay my test, i get an error message "While searching for the control an error happened at TabControl because there are maybe virtualised subelements.".

Comment: The Coded UI content index has several links for debugging tests, including two links that include the word "virtualised".

Comment: By an article in the net i have found out, that there is a bug since VS 2010.
Some developers have informed MS two years ago about that bug in recognising the UI-control hierarchy.
And this is not the only bug in Coded UI Test.
Typical Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the builder couldn't find any controls inside the `TabControl`, unless I manually searched for it. However it would not be able to click the controls even after manually adding them.

I found the fix [here](http://www.ranorex.com/forum/recognizing-elements-on-a-tabcontrol-t647.html), but we stepped away from using the builder quickly after that. So the fix worked, but we didn't test it thoroughly.

The specific part is this:

> I reviewed the sample application and found out that this seems to be a bug in the WPF TabControl when using templates, you need to specify the right “Name” in the ContentPresenter in you MainStyles.xaml TabControl style definition:
>
> `<ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />`

More information about this [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa8eb86f-5001-4af6-adb3-ceb0799a0cf3/tabcontrol-controls-are-missing-for-ui-automation?forum=wpf).